# Authentication Header not working from Angular 1.1.x to1.5.x versions while working with postman

Tags: angularjs, oauth, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

My Web API 2.-0 code is -

```
OnValidateClientAuthentication = async context =>
{

.......string clientId;

........string clientSecret;

........if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))

........{

..................if (clientId == "client1" && clientSecret == "secretKey1")

................{

....................context.Validated();

................}

...........}

}
```

I am using Bearer Authentication here.
Now I am calling this from angular-

tried two approaches -

approach 1.

in module configure -

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) 
{

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + window.btoa("Client1:secretKey1");

}
```

approach 2.

```
app.service('memberService', function ($http)

{

var headers = 
{ 

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true, 

'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 

'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 

'Authorization':'Basic ' + window.btoa("Client1:secretKey1") 


}

this.GetTocken = function (data) 

{


var response = $http({

    method: "Post",

    url: window.g_baseUrl + "accesstoken",

    headers: headers

});

return response;

};

}
```

I tried with Angular 1.1.x, to 1.5.x with no luck.
Google is telling that HttpClient class is totally. dumb
after setting Authorization header, two keys : access-control-request-method & access-control-request-headers are increasing but no key with the name of 'Authorization'.
while sending request from postman its adding Authorization key in request header.

Comment: Just a quick question - you say you're using OAuth and Bearer, but your header says Basic.  Are you doing something on the service end to handle those manually?  If you're using a library, they are generally not interchangeable.  Postman will definitely use the correct version based on what Auth Type you chose.

Comment: This code of angular first requesting token that is basic Authorization. This validates client. that token we are using as - Bearer+Token for next request to authenticate user.

Comment: Which part is failing then? The basic initial login or the subsequent bearer?